# How can i use the Vlookup with a for loop in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, vlookup

For some reason I am unable to get the below macro to work. I want to replace the month in a data link embedded in a nested IF function. Think there is an error in the VLOOKUP loop because it works fine without the loop:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IYM Data-Nat").Activate

Dim Previous_Month As String
Dim Current_Month As String

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Activate

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 12

Previous_Month = [VLOOKUP(i,X3:Y14,2,FALSE)]

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IYM Data-Nat").Activate

Current_Month = Application.Cells(2, 1)

ActiveSheet.Range("DS8:ED19").Select
   Selection.replace What:=Previous_Month, Replacement:=Current_Month,     LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False



 Next i
 End Sub
```

Have also tried with quotation marks:

```
Previous_Month = "[VLOOKUP(" & i & ",X3:Y14,2,FALSE)]"
```

There is no error but it does not work. Could someone please help?

Thank you.

Kind Regards

Comment: Never mind, I solved it using:  Ref_Month = Evaluate("VLOOKUP(" & i & ",X3:Y14,2,FALSE)") . Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps **Previous_Month = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP(i,X3:Y14,2,FALSE)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are only running a single workbook you do not have to keep referencing it; the worksheet you want to point to is sufficient.

You are having trouble since *i* is not resolving within those square brackets. I would suggest getting out of the *'square brackets evaluate'* mode and just call the worksheet function through VBA.

```
Previous_Month = application.vlookup(i, Sheets("Dashboard").Range("X3:Y14"), 2, False)
```

If you are determined to go with the evaluation route, you can construct a formula string with the `.Evaluate` command rather than the square bracket approach.

```
Previous_Month = application.evaluate("VLOOKUP(" & i & ", X3:Y14, 2, FALSE)")
```

More at [Application.Evaluate Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx)